# Sencha Touch AJAX Request Issue: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: request

Tags: ajax, request, sencha-touch, response

We are building an application using Sencha Touch 1.1 and PhoneGap 1.3.0 for deployment to iOS.

Our app makes several AJAX requests to authenticate a user and retrieve data from the server. All of our requests execute correctly with the exception of attempting to authenticate using invalid credentials.

I am using Weinre to debug the app running in the iOS simulator. 
In the Network pane the request hangs on "Pending", and in the console I receive the following error:

**error occurred: undefined:[unknown lineno]: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: request**

this error appears when the timeout value has been reached.

Here's the code for my controller:

```
Ext.regController('Login', {

login: function(options)
{
    var loader = this.application.viewport.query('#loader')[0]; 
    loader.show();
    var string = options.user + ":" + options.pass;
    var encodedString = Ext.util.Base64.encode(string) + "==";
    Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = { Authorization: "Basic " + encodedString};
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://test.com/login.do',
        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 5000,
        scope: this,
        callback: function (options, success, response) {
            if (success){
                buildingStore.load({
                    callback: function (){
                        Ext.redirect('Main/loggedIn');
                        loader.hide();
                    }
                });
                Ext.redirect('Main/loggedIn');
            }
            else {
                alert("failed");
                console.log(response.status);
                loader.hide();
                var loginFailure = new Ext.Panel ({
                    floating: true,
                    centered: true,
                    floating: true, 
                    modal: true,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    cls: 'loginError',
                    html: '<h12>Login was unsuccessful.<br>Please try again.</h12>',
                });
                loginFailure.show();    
            }
        }
    });
    Ext.Ajax.on({
        requesterror: function(conn, response, options, e){
                alert("error");
        },
        requestexception: function(conn, response, options, e){
                alert("exception");
        }
    });
    },
});
```

and a screenshot of Weinre:

[image: WEINRE Error]

Thanks for your help!
Kevin

Comment: Just in case someone else experiences this issue, the fix was updating from Sencha Touch 1.1.0 to 1.1.1. Too easy, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to sencha touch 1.1 fixes this issue. Credit to @kev_additct. Just putting it in an answer rather than a comment where it already is